# Change size of HorizontalScrollBar with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I create an excel file with VBA from Access. It creates a lot of new sheets and I would like that it shows every sheet.

I want that it looks like that:
[correct version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIXXy.png)

At the moment it looks like that:
[wrong version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xTFu.png)

I tried it with:

```
With ActiveWindow
        .DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = False
End with
```

But that removes the sidebar and the user can't use it anymore.
Any ideas?

Comment: Adjusts the ratio `ActiveWindow.TabRatio = 0.446`

Comment: Worked perfectly. thank you

Comment: @newguy please post your comment as an answer, so that the OP can select as such for the rest of the users to see this question is answered. Thanks

Comment: @Jean-PierreOosthuizen okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub TabRatio()
   ActiveWindow.TabRatio = 0.174      'Adjust Ratio according to the need.
End Sub
```